# C++ template function, same type, multiple instantiations: shares one same copy of code? EVEN in different cpp/object files

Tags: c++

For example, consider the following code:

```
// f.h
template <typename T>
int f(T x) {
   return x+1;
}
```

If we instantiate it in both `foo.cpp` and `bar.cpp`:

```
//foo.cpp instantiation:
int i = f(1);
```

and

```
//bar.cpp instantiation:
int j = f(2);
```

Will the final program uses only one copy of code? Is that so, when `bar.cpp` is hidden but only the object file `bar.o` is provided?

I think, since each cpp files are compiled independently, both `foo.o` and `bar.o` must contains `f(int)`.  The linker should see same duplicate signature, and use only one copy.  Am I right?

Comment: Each implementation use its own approach, see [this for gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Template-Instantiation.html)

Comment: Before you get a program it goes through the compilation stage and linker stage. I don't know for sure exactly when it gets removed, but it would have to be the worst IDE in the world to actually create a finished program with two copies of the same instantiated template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the linker will generally fold duplicate identical template instantiations away. Doing so is pretty much required to avoid an explosion in binary size when templates are involved, and to maintain some standard required invariants such as equivalence of function pointers. This behavior is sometimes called *fold by name*.

Beyond that, [some linkers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15168924/149138) will even fold away all symbols that *happen* to be identical in content (i.e., compile the same code), even if they don't originate from the same definition. This is sometimes called *fold by value*, but unless done carefully may break the letter of the standard (i.e., because function pointers to different functions now compare equal).

Comment: Couldn't the compiler just put a nop slide above the function and have each instantiation link to a different nop? The performance effect would be negligible while still getting nearly the full binary reduction of function folding.

Comment: @Derek - indeed, I think stuff like that happens in other specific scenarios. Part of the problem in practice though would be that the compiler doesn't really have all the info to make this decision while compiling a single TU: for all it knows this will be the only copy of the function in the final binary. If not, how many nops should it add? Then there's the fact that is' actually the linker that has to do most of the work here and traditionally linkers don't understand any of this, just fairly basic symbol to address stuff (exceptions exist, see how TLS access is handled, for example).

Comment: Within a single TU though a compiler do it itself.