# Variadic template argument deduction - c++11 - many functions linked to one

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates

I'm experiencing some strange occurrences regarding varidaic templates that I never saw before.
In order to keep it simple i'll give a simple example of what I was trying to achieve, the real code is a bit more involved.

So I have one function that looks like:

```
template <typename T, typename F, typename ... Args> 
static T Func( std::string str, Args&& ... args )
{
 ... Do something
}
```

I then call this function a number of times from different locations, where most times the passed types are different. But when I debug this, when I look for the symbol of Func, I get that the same function address has a number of different symbols:

```
00000000`70ba4ae0 Func<unsigned long,unsigned long (__stdcall*)(wchar_t const *),wchar_t const *>

00000000`70ba4ae0 Func<void *,void * (__stdcall*)(unsigned int),unsigned int>

00000000`70ba4ae0 Func<int,int (__stdcall*)(void *),void *>
```

So they are all basically the same function. When I try to call for example:

```
call Func<void *,void * (__stdcall*)(unsigned int),unsigned int>
```

In the debugger I see:

```
call Func<int,int (__stdcall*)(void *),void *>
```

I can see that there is a generated symbol for every template function instance, but every such instance that has the same number of arguments and the arguments are the same byte-size are just linked to one function.

While I can understand why this may happen, but is there a way to force each function to be standalone?

Comment: Possibly relevant: [GCC(/Clang): Merging functions with identical instructions (COMDAT folding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168924)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was indeed COMDAT folding. Turning off the OPT:ICF and OPT:REF flags did the trick. Although worth noting that compiling with VS 2017 with the flags produced more "sensible" results than compiling the same code with VS 2013.