# Is the address of a C function symbol constant between compiles

Tags: c++, c, serialization, dll, shared-libraries

I have been experimenting with symbol visibility in my shared library and noticed that the address / value of an exported function symbol does not seem to change. Are these addresses constant between compiles, or is this a coincidence?

The addresses where obtained on a Virtual Machine running Arch Linux using the command `readelf` with option `-W` and `--dyn-syms`.

The reason I'm asking is that **I am wondering if the address of a templated C++ function could be used as an uuid for an object type.** This is of interest in my serialization routine where I would like to setup an id system which is constant between compiles (object types are registered statically at initialization time, so order is not defined).

Comment: It could potentially be problematic... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168924/gcc-clang-merging-functions-with-identical-instructions-comdat-folding

Comment: It might not even be the same between two runs of the same binary: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Comment: "Is the address of a C function symbol constant between compiles" - No. You have no such guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

If build process is unchanged (i.e. compiler, linker, Makefiles and code remain the same) the *static* address in ELF file will not change either. But if any component changes, all bets are off.

More importantly, *dynamic* address (assigned by dynamic loader) will be different on each run due to [address-space randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) in modern Linux distros so you should not rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

When you build your code you can choose either to build it position **dependent** or position **independent** this has nothing to do with static build (though you can't build a position independent static binary). Position dependent binaries (given the same sources, compiler and build flags) will always generate the same addresses, but as I say further down, I wouldn't rely on it in release.

This is supplied by GCC's options `-fPIE` (Position independent executable), `-fPIC` (Position independent code), `-pie`. ELF executable files can be built as either position *dependent* or *independent* but shared objects (libraries) will **always** be built as position **independent** as you need to be able to load them in a random location given to you by the OS. From GCC's MAN page:

```
-fPIC
If supported for the target machine, emit position-independent code, suitable for dynamic linking and avoiding any limit on the size of the global offset table. 

-fpie
-fPIE
These options are similar to -fpic and -fPIC, but generated position independent code can be only linked into executables. Usually these options are used when -pie GCC option will be used during linking.

-pie
Produce a position independent executable on targets which support it. For predictable results, you must also specify the same set of options that were used to generate code (-fpie, -fPIE, or model suboptions) when you specify this option.
```

When loading a PIC shared object you cannot assume it will reside in the same place for each run, as it might be affected by ASLR that is driven by the kernel.

In any way I don't think it's a good practice to use memory addresses as uuids to classes as these might change, even more so if these template classes are implemented as part of a shared object.