# C++ Template class methods that do not use template parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, parameters

I have a class with M number of methods, and only one method performs read-only operations on a std::array.  The rest of the M-1 methods do not use the std::array.  Code below.  Assume I can't break up this class.

My concerns are:

1. This code is little ugly because, as mentioned, only 1 method uses the parameter N.
2. If I instantiate Bar 100 times each with different N's, then doesn't that bloat the code?  Like I said, only 1 method uses the parameter N, yet my understanding is that I'll get 99*(M-1) extra copies of effectively the same method.

That being said, is it standard to use a vector or a C-array instead to avoid template?  Will I be sacrificing any potential performance?

```
//bar.h
template<int N>
class Bar
{
  public:
    Bar(const std::array<Foo, N>& arr);
    void method_one();
    void method_two();
    void method_three();
    ...
  private:
    const std::array<Foo, N> arr_;
};

template<int N> Bar<N>::Bar(const std::array<Foo, N>& arr) :
  arr_(arr)
  {}

template<int N> void Bar<N>::method_one()
{
   //....
}

template<int N> void Bar<N>::method_two()
{
   //....
}

//etc
```

Comment: Why would you hae to a template-argument-depedent type, if you never access it as such?

Comment: I want to pass the class constructor a std::array and store a copy of it as a class member.

Comment: Do the other functions access that member? If not, you can just use inheritance.

Comment: You can assume very few methods access that member (above I said 1 out of M as an example).  Inheritance might solve it, but sounds like a hack.

Comment: It's not really a hack, and it's also done in the standard-library (even if we only look at what the standard says about `<iostream>`, let alone what any implementation does).

Comment: I found this link relevant: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Optimizing_C++/Code_optimization/Memory_access#Template_code_independent_of_parameters .   They recommend creating function, but that would mean I would have M-1 functions to redirect to, which also sounds inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your compiler might (or might be induced to) fold identical functions even if they have different signatures.
Whether that is legal (and how to force it), see here:

[Do distinct functions have distinct addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26533740)
[Is an implementation allowed to site two identical function definitions at the same address, or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14188612)

Next, if members of your template are independent of template-arguments, consider moving them to a base-class:

```
class Bar_base {
    // Move everything here not dependent on template-arguments.
    // Can be done multiple times if useful
}
template<int N> class Bar : public Bar_base {
    // Everything dependent on `N`, and maybe some using-declarations
    //  for proper overloading
}
```

All implementations of the standard library do it extensively, and if you look at `<iostream>`, it's even codified in the standard.

Answer (score 0):

If only the constructor uses std::array<...,N> you may turn your templated class into a standard class with templated constructor. Further more I would hope that the compiler is clever enough to not copy 100s of code fragment that do not have any dependency on N.

```
class Bar
{
  public:
    template<int N>
    Bar(const std::array<Foo, N>& arr);
...
...
}
```

EDIT: Crap !! This doesn't seem to compile... It works with parameters like

```
class Bar {
public:
 template<int N>
 Bar(const int (& a)[N]);
```

Comment: What about the class member arr_?  How would I declare it?

Comment: I missed arr_ all together. And my approach doesn't even seem to compile with std::array<...,N> although I regularly use it for fixed sized arrays ... sigh.