# template class with functions that do not use the template

Tags: c++, templates, static-libraries

I am jumping through hoops to reduce inheritance.

I read one similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877675/c-template-class-methods-that-do-not-use-template-parameter). It shows how the issue can be resolved using a base class. I try to loose inheritance, so I am looking for something different - more along the lines of annotation.

I create and compile a template class with one specialisation (`normal`). The method that requires the template is in the header (`Mixer.hpp`). The method that does not require the template is in the cpp file (`Mixer.cpp`). When compiled into a static library, the cpp part only gets compiled as one specialisation (`Mixer<normal>`). The compiler does not know about (`awsome`) at that time. Importing the resulting static library into another project and attempting to create a different generic (`awsome`) class results in a linker error because obviously the library does not contain that method identifier (`Mixer<awesome>::noTemplateInvolved`). However the code for the normal implementation is as good as any so really the linker could just link to the existing source of the other template version (`Mixer<?dontcare?>::noTemplateInvolved`). All that the compiler has to do is to mark it appropriately for the linker.

Here is source code that results in a linker error:

```
//Target compiled to Provider.lib
//Mixer.hpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct normal { static void log() { cout << "normal\n"; } };

template<typename output = normal>
class Mixer
{
public:
    void callingTemplate();
    void noTemplateInvolved();
};

template<typename output>
void Mixer<output>::callingTemplate() { output::log(); }
//Mixer.cpp
#include "Mixer.hpp"
void Mixer<>::noTemplateInvolved()
{
    cout << "noTemplateInvolved\n";
}

//Target Compiled to User.exe
//This target imports Provider.lib
#include <Provider\Mixer.hpp>
#pragma comment(lib, "Provider.lib")

struct awsome { static void log() { cout << "awsome\n"; } };

int main()
{
    Mixer<> n;
    n.callingTemplate();
    n.noTemplateInvolved();

    Mixer<awsome> a;
    a.callingTemplate();
    a.noTemplateInvolved(); //linker error here
    return 0;
}
```

The class `Mixer<awsome>` can link to the method `callingTemplate` because its definition is in the header and the compiler creates that function. At `User.exe` compile time the definition of `noTemplateInvolved` is hidden from the compiler. The compiler can not create that method and linking has to fail.

There are three solutions that I am aware of.

- move the definition of `noTemplateInvolved` to the header.
- include the cpp file
- inherit from a baseclass

I am looking for another solution. The body of `noTemplateInvolved` really has nothing to do with the template. I would like to annotate the method in the header. I want the compiler to know it should always use the same base implementation regardless of the template.

Is that at all possible?

EDIT: Annotated that boring paragraph at the beginning a bit.

Comment: If it has nothing to do with the template, why is it a member, and a non-static one at that? You could implement it as a separate, non-template non-member function, and maybe have just a member stub forwarding to it - you'll have to provide the definition for the stub, but it will be just one line that will most likely be inlined. Is this the kind of thing you're looking for? Anyway, I'm not sure why you wouldn't want to choose the non-dependent base solution; maybe explaining this decision in the question will shed more light on your requirements.

Comment: You can use **explicit template instantiation**. Why you don't want to move move non-template functions to base class? It has no overhead in this case.

Comment: The end goal is refactoring. If I can annotate something in a header I don't have to touch the implementation. If nothing else this will be educational for me. Explicit instantiation would not work in the presented case - the library is compiled before the 'struct awsome' is known. I will try the extern keyword though I think it is deprecated.

Comment: In my real production code I moved on to using a base class, however I do have another idea that I will implement shortly to see if that gets me closer to an annotation form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turns out to be a base class as suggested in the comments. One of the reasons I wanted a base class is that I did not want to refactor. Refactoring using a base class is actually really simple.

Rename the `original` class to `original_base`.
Inherit from `original_template` inherits from `original_base`. Make sure to copy the contructor and pass through all the arguments to the base class.
The statement `using original = original_template<your default case here>` ensures that no other source code has to be modified just yet.

Applied to the example above I ended up doing something like this:

```
//Target compiled to Provider.lib
//Mixer.hpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct normal { static void log() { cout << "normal\n"; } };

class Mixer_Base
{
private:
    int mixcount;
public:
    Mixer_Base(int count);
    void noTemplateInvolved();
};

template<typename output = normal>
class Mixer_tempalte : public Mixer_Base
{
public:
    Mixer_tempalte(int count) : Mixer_Base(count)
    {}
    void callingTemplate();
};

template<typename output>
void Mixer_tempalte<output>::callingTemplate()
{
    output::log();
}

using Mixer = Mixer_tempalte<>;
//Mixer.cpp
#include "Mixer.hpp"

void Mixer_Base::noTemplateInvolved()
{
    cout << "noTemplateInvolved\n";
}

Mixer_Base::Mixer_Base(int count) : mixcount(count)
{}

//Target Compiled to User.exe
//This target imports Provider.lib
#include <Provider\Mixer.hpp>
#pragma comment(lib, "Provider.lib")

struct awsome { static void log() { cout << "awsome\n"; } };

int main()
{
    Mixer n(4);
    n.callingTemplate();
    n.noTemplateInvolved();

    Mixer_tempalte<awsome> a(3);
    a.callingTemplate();
    a.noTemplateInvolved();
    return 0;
}
```

In a way an annotation feels just like the base class feels. Everything in the base class is now annotated the way I wanted it to be, though this does not reduce inheritance.