Is there a way to pass a template type to a grand-child class without making a child template in C++?
I have a rather complex set of C++ object dependencies and I'm using templates to manage object specialization. I find templates confusing but they avoid a lot of problems with object casting that I really like. I now find myself needing to convert a class into a template simply so that I can pass the passed template type to a subclass - the class receiving the template specialization doesn't care about the template type because it operates on the type's base class. This class has a lot of logic that I don't want to specialize and I'm trying to find a way to avoid that.
Here's a simplified example. Call this file "cars.h":
#include <iostream>

using std::cout, std::endl;

class baseEngine { public: void start() { cout << "vroom" << endl; }};
class GasEngine : public baseEngine {};
class DieselEngine : public baseEngine {};

// Needs "T"
template <class T>
class baseVehicle {
    public: T engine;
};

// Only needs "T" to pass to the baseVehicle
template <class T>
class Body : public baseVehicle<T> {
    public:
    void drive();   // I don't want to duplicate all of these foreach engine T.
    void park();    // Some of these use the baseEngine interface but not all.
    void honk();    // None of them need to use the specialized "T" variant.
    void brake();   // What are my options? Can I ::forward<> something?
    virtual void fillup() = 0;  // Derived classes need to provide this.
};

// These use the specialized template "T" values.
class GasCar    : public Body<GasEngine> { public: void fillup() {}};
class DieselCar : public Body<DieselEngine> {};
// HydrogenEngine, NuclearEngine, HampsterEngine, etc.

// Other stuff that makes this tricky
class baseBadge {};
class BlueOval : public baseBadge {};
class baseFord : public BlueOval {};

// The thing I actually need to deal with
class FordFreestyle : public baseFord, public GasCar {};
class FordRollsCoal : public baseFord, public DieselCar {};

And here is "cars.cpp":
#include "cars.h"

// There's no need to make many copies of this.
template<class T>
void Body<T>::drive() { this->engine.start(); }

// Conceptually, this should work logically but it gives linker errors.
template<>
void Body<baseEngine>::drive() { this->engine.start(); }

// This is the working non-template code, but "template <>" undefines this as its own class
void Body::drive() { this->engine.start(); }
// void Body::honk() { /* nothing to do with the engine */ }
// void Body::brake() { /* nothing to do with the engine */ }


int main()
{
    FordFreestyle myCar;
    myCar.drive();
    myCar.fillup();

    // GasCar gCar;
    // DieselCar dCar;
    // dCar.drive();
    // dCar.fillup();

    return 0;
}

This doesn't seem like that unusual a construction but what is the answer? I realize I can put all this logic into the header file but that seems like a huge waste, and I really don't care for that as an idiom. But is that just how it is? Does the compiler or linker drop all the functions that don't depend on <T> or are these dozens of specialized functions getting called just because that's how the templates defined them?

Why are baseVehicle and Body not just the same clas (template)?

At the end of the day, a Body has an engine inside. So, one way or another, you need to specify what type of engine a particular instance of Body is going to carry. Either via a compile-time polymorphism (template parameter) or run-time polymorphism (have all engine classes derive from EngineInterface with pure virtual functions; have Body store EngineInterface* pointer so you can provide the right type of engine at run-time). Pick your poison.

@DavisHerring In this specific instance, "Body" would be a base class for "Sedan" or "Flatbed", but the example is only meant to be representative. I'm trying to keep it simple.

Perhaps the type of body and the type of engine should be separate independent attributes of a car, not related by inheritance.

@IgorTandetnik You're probably right. My example may be oversimplified, but part of my question is asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877675/c-template-class-methods-that-do-not-use-template-parameter In my actual code I have a parallel set of classes that (trying to keep the metaphor) generate efficiency reports with a configurable accounting unit (gallons vs liters). The goal is to generate a report and so the report class is assuming that it has a car part so it can test drive specific car part functions. That may be a bit obtuse, but the scope is coming more into focus...

@IgorTandetnik Yes, you are correct: I can use templates, or I can use base classes. I was trying to replace a bunch of top-level dynamic_cast<> calls with a single template that just knew the right type. It would be nice if there were an easy solution to this, but I've reverted back to using casts in each high-level base-class' virtual getter function. :-/
